# Namespace for StyledIconOptions,StyledMarker in C#.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, subgurim-maps

i am using the Subgurim.Controles google maps in my project.when i use StyledIconOptions,StyledIcon,StyledMarker it show missing the assembly or directive. what is the name space is required for this issue...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Subgurim.Controles;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GLatLng latLng = new GLatLng(50, 10);
            GMap1.setCenter(latLng);

            GIcon icon = new GIcon();
            icon.image = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/circular/greencirclemarker.png";
            icon.iconSize = new GSize(32, 32);
            icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(16, 16);
            icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(25, 7);

            StyledIconOptions iconOptions1 = new StyledIconOptions()
            {
                Text = "Hi",
                Color = Color.Blue,
                Fore = Color.Red,
                StarColor = Color.Green
            };

            StyledIcon icon1 = new StyledIcon(StyledIconType.Marker, iconOptions1);

            StyledMarker styledMarker1 = new StyledMarker(latLng, icon1);

            StyledIconOptions iconOptions2 = new StyledIconOptions()
            {
                Text = "Hi, I'm a bubble!",
                Color = Color.Orange,
                Fore = Color.PaleGreen,
            };

            StyledIcon icon2 = new StyledIcon(StyledIconType.Bubble, iconOptions2);

            StyledMarker styledMarker2 = new StyledMarker(latLng + new GLatLng(1.0, 1.0), icon2);

            GInfoWindow window1 = new GInfoWindow(styledMarker1, "You can user StyledMarker as any other marker!");
            GInfoWindow window2 = new GInfoWindow(styledMarker2, "You can user StyledMarker as any other marker!");

            GMap1.Add(window1);
            GMap1.Add(window2);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the namespace is

```
using Subgurim.Controles;
using Subgurim.Controles.Classes.UtilityLibrary;
using Subgurim.Controles.Classes.UtilityLibrary.Options;
```

regards